# Get MIME type with Scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy, mime-types

I just want to get the MIME type of an URL with Scrapy. I will process files in different ways according to the file type, so I need to know which type of file I downloaded.

Is MIME type in any variable or in Scrapy Response object?

I don't want to recognize a file by the extension since many images on Internet don't use it, example: . I want to use MIME and extensions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there is. The Response object has a parameter called "headers". Check http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html. That attribute is a dictionary that must have the Content-Type field.